# Get property from or type of ascx file from the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

Basically I want a boolean property in a ascx control which could be read without loading the full control (I'd like to avoid `LoadControl` triggering the events).

I have database rows which store what different sets of controls should be seen by different users by the virtual path to the controls.  I need to add the ability to print these controls, but only certain controls will have the ability to print.

I was thinking of having an interface for those controls that support it, then as i build the print page i check the type of each control to see if it has that interface or not.
Along those lines I'm wondering if there is any way to get the control type from the url of a file.  I know `Page.LoadControl(url).GetType()` would work but i would like to avoid the overhead of building the control if possible.

**Reason:**
Since the ability to print might be added to other controls during development having the code of the ascx file store that property in some way would be ideal.  Rather than needing to update properties in each database list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Type` of the `UserControl` by using the `BuildManager` class in the `System.Web.Compilation` namespace.

```
Type ctrlType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/PrintableControl.ascx");
bool isPrintable = typeof(IPrintable).IsAssignableFrom(ctrlType);
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot.  Though before I accepted this answer your rep was at 777 and you have 7 badges, so it shows "777 * 7" hah